# What is the need for the code snippet below, and can I get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Please keep in mind that I am building an application that will handle very sensitive data.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

Comment: read the documentation and decide for yourself - http://expressjs.com/api.html (took me 0.37 seconds to find that on google)

Comment: That explains nothing. I am asking a question about BodyParser. I need an explaination

Comment: Did you remove it? What happened?

Comment: So look at the documentation for BodyParser. Read this: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 0):

The main function of body parser is to allow you to parse the body of a POST request to your Express webserver. If you do not plan to have your application accept POST requests, then you do not need this middleware, otherwise it is quite essential.